# Wildfly 8.2.0 unexpected shutdown

Tags: java, wildfly-8

I have a Wildfly 8.2.0 server that just shuts down for no apparent reason. There are no exceptions, and server shuts down gracefully. My question is very similar to this one here [Wildfly 8.1.0 shutting down automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287774/wildfly-8-1-0-shutting-down-automatically), which is also unanswered.

There is a daemon thread used to clean up idle sessions and an executor service used to process some large requests. Is there a way to see what triggered the shutdown? Any thoughts on what could cause this?